# QGIS: error in conversion from vector to raster

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I've having troubles with the raster conversion from a vector polygonal file.

This is the error in the log window:

```
INFO    GDAL execution console output
             ERROR 1: Wrong value for -outsize parameter.
```

Does someone have any advice?

Comment: can you update/edit your question to show the command used?

Comment: The command I used is: GDAL_rasterize.

Comment: are you able to edit your question to post that command and would recommend you copy and paste the entire command with flags, input and output you tried

Comment: 'BURN' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '561919.973711453,592683.1298934325,4455222.109075321,4470993.264253331 [EPSG:32633]', 'FIELD' : None, 'HEIGHT' : 0, 'INIT' : 0, 'INPUT' : ' 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users//AppData/Local/OUTPUT.tif', 'UNITS' : 0, 'WIDTH' : 0

Comment: You must feed in the size of the output raster as pixels with the width and height boxes. They have value 0 as default and zero by zero sized raster is nothing.